# .htaccess for CodeIgniter

Tags: .htaccess

My CodeIgniter structure :
    public/
    application/
    system/

I don't want anyone to access http://exampble.com/public, allow only the application to access the resource. I tries to create the file .htaccess in directory with the content 'Deny from all', so the user can't access this directory. But my application can't access as well.

How can I solve this problem?

Please give me any idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From its name, it appears that you're using the 'public' directory to store relevant images and css for your site.

If that is the case, then there's no way you can prevent users from accessing it, unless you don't want to serve images or display styling for your website.

You may however enable what's called hot-link protection which will check for the referrer for each request (not very secure, but thought it might help you out).